# Normalising squeezed position eigenket?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wigner-transform, squeezed-states

I want to find the effect of squeezing operator $S(r) = \exp \big[r(\hat{a}^2 - \hat{a}^{{\dagger}^2})\big]$
 on $|q\rangle$ i.e. $S(r)|q\rangle$.

I proceed as follows:

$$S(r)\hat{q}|q\rangle = S(r)q |q\rangle
     $$
Also
 $$S(r)\hat{q}|q\rangle = S(r)\hat{q}S(r)^{\dagger}S(r)|q\rangle  = e^r \hat{q}(S(r)|q\rangle)
     $$
using $S(r)\hat{q}S(r)^{\dagger} = e^r \hat{q}$.
Combining above two equations yield
    $$\hat{q}(S(r)|q\rangle)  = e^{-r} q (S(r)|q\rangle)
$$
Hence, $S(r)|q\rangle$ is eigenket of $\hat{q}$ operator with eigenvalue $ e^{-r} q $ i.e.
    $$S(r)|q\rangle = N |e^{-r} q\rangle
$$
where N is the normalization factor.

How to determine normalization factor $N$?

For more [details](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=G2zKNooOeKcC&printsec=frontcover&dq=pieter%20kok%20symplectic%20tranformation%20wigner&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi64cOb89vhAhUf7nMBHX1bA2cQ6AEIKjAA#v=onepage&q=wigner&f=false) see Chapter 8 of Introduction to Optical Quantum Information Processing
By Pieter Kok, Brendon W. Lovett.

Another ref: P.No. 12, arxiv: [1212.5340](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1212/1212.5340.pdf)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If 
$$
S(z) = \exp\{z (\hat a^\dagger)^2 -z^*\hat a^2\}
$$
then $S^\dagger(z) = S(-z)=S^{-1}(z)$, so $S(z)$ is unitary.  It does not change the nomalization of any state therefore.  You should be careful however: Your
$|q\rangle$  is an eigenstate of the position operator, so it is not itself normalizable to start with.

Comment: S(r)|q> is normalized; however, |e^(-r) q> is not. Here, I want to find N which normalizes the same.

Comment: @Mark Robinson. I do not understand your comment. For any state $|f\rangle$, both $S(r) |f\rangle$ and $|f\rangle$ have the same normalization. If  you had a nomalizable  eigenstate localized near $q$ now you have one that has been moved to $e^{-r}q$, but it  still has the same normalization.

Comment: Yes S(r)|f> and |f> will have the same normalization, but R.H.S. involves |e^(-r) f>, thus requiring a normalization factor.

Comment: I have updated a link in the question.

Comment: @Mark Robinson. I can't access the book, but the problem is that you do not specify what you mean by $|q\rangle$. If you mean the state with wavefunction $\langle x|q\rangle = \delta(x-q)$ then $|e^{-r}q\rangle$ is no more  normalizable than is $|q\rangle$.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I have added a snapshot as well as another reference. Could you kindly recheck?

Comment: @Mark Robinson. His eq 8.31 is  nonsense since we cannot normalize $|e^{-r}q\rangle$. What he is trying to say,  however, is some muddled combination  of   $\langle q|q'\rangle =\delta(q-q')$  and  $\delta(e^{-r} x)= e^r\delta(x)$ so he thinks that $\langle e^{-r} q|e^{-r} q'\rangle = \delta(e^{-r}q-e^{-r}q')= e^r\delta(q-q')$. Again let me stress that this is nonsense.